# how to stop "ERROR: wget failed to download http://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/get-upstream-version.pl.gz.pgp"

Tags: debian, knoppix

I keep getting

> ERROR: wget failed to download http://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/get-upstream-version.pl.gz.pgp

when I try to install `flashplugin-nonfree_3.2_i386.deb` from debian.org.

How do i correct this problem? I'm using Knoppix 7.2.0 installed on sda1 with persistent 32 bit knoppix-data-aes encrypted. 8 gigs of free space on hdd and 8 gigs of RAM in the box; 
I started having this problem after I typed `knoppix64` instead of `knoppix` at the initial boot up screen and then tried to boot into the 32 bit kernel. Everything seemed to work fine except when I tried to install the flash player Debian file mentioned in this post.

Answer (score 0):

find out what the script is with that wget line and amend it so it includes --no-check-certificate

The Debian side of things requires that you find out what the script is and edit it as described above.  Or update Debian, maybe your Debian or an aspect of it is out of date. Or maybe the instructions you read were out of date.

It looks like perhaps the instructions you read were out of date. I don't think running knoppix64 or knoppix would make a difference. And personally, at the initial bootup screen when i've used Knoppix. I have always pushed ENTER and it loaded the right one on the 32-bit laptop I ran it on. There is also a config file to automatically type something at that screen. But I don't think that has anything to do with this error you're getting.

I think the instructions you read for installing it were just out of date. Here is the incorrect, and the correct, wget command

Notice that the incorrect command says `To connect to people.debian.org insecurely, use`--no-check-certificate'.`  So that should lead you to see the correct command is one that has that switch.

Here's the wget side of things.

Notice the difference between the command that fails and the command that works

**FAILS**

```
C:\treesize>wget http://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/get-upstrea
m-version.pl.gz.pgp
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = c:\program files\gnuwin32/etc/wgetrc
--2014-08-02 16:04:06--  http://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/get
-upstream-version.pl.gz.pgp
Resolving people.debian.org... 5.153.231.30
Connecting to people.debian.org|5.153.231.30|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/get-upstream-vers
ion.pl.gz.pgp [following]
--2014-08-02 16:04:06--  https://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/ge
t-upstream-version.pl.gz.pgp
Connecting to people.debian.org|5.153.231.30|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify people.debian.org's certificate, issued by `/C=FR/O=GANDI S
AS/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to people.debian.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

**WORKS**

```
C:\treesize>wget http://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/get-upstrea
m-version.pl.gz.pgp --no-check-certificate
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = c:\program files\gnuwin32/etc/wgetrc
--2014-08-02 16:04:15--  http://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/get
-upstream-version.pl.gz.pgp
Resolving people.debian.org... 5.153.231.30
Connecting to people.debian.org|5.153.231.30|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/get-upstream-vers
ion.pl.gz.pgp [following]
--2014-08-02 16:04:16--  https://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/ge
t-upstream-version.pl.gz.pgp
Connecting to people.debian.org|5.153.231.30|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify people.debian.org's certificate, issued by `/C=FR/O=GANDI
 SAS/CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1872 (1.8K) [application/pgp-encrypted]
Saving to: `get-upstream-version.pl.gz.pgp'

100%[======================================>] 1,872       --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-08-02 16:04:16 (14.2 MB/s) - `get-upstream-version.pl.gz.pgp' saved [1872/1
872]
```

---

Also, I recognize there may be an issue with adobe flash being non-free(not open source and thus somewhat excommunicated), but it may be possible to install it with apt-get or aptitude.  A google suggested Trying `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: Great Command="sudo update-ca-certificates"! I tried the "sudo update-ca-certificates" command and the problem stopped and the flash player file installed properly again, just like before!!! Joy!  In earlier times, I am delighted to say that I found a web site that showed me a "one-click-solution" to the flash player download dilemma:  
http://robrohan.com/2013/06/12/watching-youtube-videos-without-flash.html
 This web site gave me a link>>> "drag and drop" THAT link onto my Bookmarks drop down menu, then, when youtube video wants flash player, I click the link and video will play!

Comment: I did do sudo apt-get update previously but that didn't correct the problem. I did the update just a few days ago too. When I first installed knoppix 7.2.0 on sda1 a month ago, the download worked fine when I sudo dpkg -i fl*6.deb

Answer (score 0):

Maybe proxy issues.
verify environment with command "env" 
verify proxies variables 
http_proxy
ftp_proxy

this issue maybe because apt-get / aptitute have correct proxy settings but wget dont know what proxy ask.

I solved this problem setting up the /etc/environment file with http_proxy and ftp_proxy
like this:

```
# /etc/environment --------------------------------------
http_proxy=http://<username>:password@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/
HTTP_PROXY=http://<username>:password@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/
https_proxy=http://<username>:password@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://<username>:password@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/
ftp_proxy=http://<username>:password@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/
FTP_PROXY=http://<username>:password@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com,10.0.0.0/8
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com,10.0.0.0/8
```